# In Entity Framework Code First can I not have a navigation property on dependent entity

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Assume the following schema

```
class Person{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Province> Provinces {get;set;}
}

class Province{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public virtual ICollection<Person> Residents {get;set;}
}
```

Is there anyway that I can hide or not define the Residents property? It makes no sense in the context of the application and it feels like I'm making a concession on the DTO just to fit in with Code First schema. i.e. I don't want to be able to get the people that belong to a province. In the normal EF with a DBML I could delete the navigation property to achieve this.

I've had a look through the fluentAPI docs and can't find anything that seems like it would cover the situation.

In an ideal world I should be mapping the Entity poco DTO to a domain class but I'm just being lazy and seeing if it's possible to avoid that.

[edit]
I did manage to solve with this, but EF what have you done to my poor poco!!

```
  class Province{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     protected virtual ICollection<Person> Residents {get;set;}

     internal class ProvinceMapping : EntityConfiguration<Province>
     {
          public ProvinceMapping()
          {
              HasMany(p => p.Residents);
          }
     }
```

Then in the context

```
protect void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configuration.Add(new Province.ProvinceMapping());
}
```

Comment: "*In the normal EF with a DBML I could delete the navigation property to achieve this.*" With Code-First you can do the same: just delete the collection property from the `Providence` class.

Comment: yeah,  sorry I was paraphrasing from a model I'm using at the moment which is actually a many-many relationship. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the mapping with only one navigation property:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Province> Provinces {get;set;}
}

class Province
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class PersonMapping : EntityConfiguration<Person>
{
     public PersonMapping()
     {
         this.HasMany(p => p.Provinces)
             .WithMany()
             .Map(m =>
             {
                 m.MapLeftKey("PersonId");
                 m.MapRightKey("ProvinceId");
                 m.ToTable("PersonProvinces");
             });
     }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configuration.Add(new PersonMapping());
}
```

Using `WithMany()` without parameter is the key here. It tells EF that the relationship is many-to-many but one end is not exposed as navigation collection in the model.

Comment: works like a charm thanks. As I'm not bothered about the table names and mappings I just used the following in the OnModelCreating and then didn't need the separate Mapping class at all.
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(p => p.Provinces).WithMany();